# Any details on deep inelastic scattering?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, scattering

The [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering) is rather scanty and I couldn't find more info in previous questions. I hope you will cot consider this as a multiple question since all queries are details of a single issue.

I'd like to know

- what level of KE energy is necessary to pass from elastic to inelastic scattering, if in that energy is included the huge amount of electric energy due to attraction (which I suppose in the excess of quintillions of eV);
- roughly how many different outcomes occur and if they are related to increased energy and if such outcomes are different from the one due to proton-proton collision;
- lastly, what are the angles of deflection and, most of all: if a proton shows 3 points of deflection (I suppose ) on one side, does that not mean the points of deflection must be at least six?

---

Edit

There are simple questions that surely can be answered without QFT or math, such as: why is not electrostatic force considered? the angle of deflection is surely influenced by the charge (+/-) of the parton involved. 2) what are the most frequent outcomes of a collision? are they different from proton-proton collision?

Comment: try to read this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/scatele.html

Comment: @annav, thanks , so at 10 GeV the proton splits, but KE does not include the huge electrostatic energy?and it does not say in how many different ways the proton can break up. Can the electron also rebound besides deflecting? and are the 3 points of deflection relative to one side? does this indicte that there are at least 6 partons?

Comment: It cannot be answered  in the way you think. It needs graduate courses in quantum field theory to understand how the interactions are modeled. https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/theses/klasen/duwentaester_msc.pdf

Comment: There are simple questions that surely can be answered without QFT or math, such as: why is not electrostatic force considered? the angle of deflection is surely influenced by the charge (+/-) of the parton involved. 2) what are the most frequent outcomes of a collision? are they different from proton-proton collision?

Comment: These questions have to do with quantum mechanical entities/particles and cannot be answered without using quantum mechanics and field theory for the production of particles in deep inelastic.

Comment: "which I suppose in the excess of quintillions of eV". You suppose wrong. $ke^2/r^2\sim 1~\rm MeV$ gives the characteristic scale of the electric potential energy, which is just a biiiit less than $1\,000\,000\,000\,000~\rm MeV$.

Comment: Also you really do have too many sub-questions here. Feel free to ask them separately.

Comment: @Chris, there are no sub-questions here, only details of the same experiment, and readers can choose the one they can answer.You yourself corrected my estimate, yet did not explain why the electric force, whatever its value, is not considered , which may invalidate the result of the experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get hold of Riordan's book *The Hunting Of The Quark* for a detailed and very readable account of how all that stuff works.